# Pull-back of algebraic cycle and moving lemma

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Suppose $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is morphism between non-singular projective varieties, and $Z$ is a codimension-$c$ cycle of $Y$. From the chapter on [Intersection Theory](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/intersection.pdf) of Stack Project, for rational equivalence relation, the pull back of the cycle class $[Z]$ represented by $Z$ is
\begin{equation}
f^*([Z])=(pr_X)_*([\Gamma_f] \cdot (pr_Y)^*[Z])
\end{equation}
When the scheme theoretic inverse image $f^{-1}(Z)$ is also of codimension $c$ and $Z$ is Cohen-Macaulay at the images of the generic points of $f^{-1}(Z)$, then the pull-back $f^*[Z]$ is just the cycle associated to the scheme $[f^{-1}(Z)]$.

**Question**: for an arbitrary cycle $Z$, does there exist a cycle $Z'$ which is rationally equivalent to $Z$ such that the codimension of $f^{-1}(Z')$ is $c$ and
\begin{equation}
f^*([Z])=[f^{-1}(Z')]
\end{equation}

Comment: To be clear "this technical condition" refers only to the equation $f^*([Z])=[f^{-1}(Z')]$, or are you asking for the stronger requirement that $f^{-1}(Z')$ be of codimension c and $Z'$ be CM at images of generic points of its inverse image?

Comment: @Stephen Thank you. I have made a change!

Comment: This is just Chow moving lemma？